# Linking Woocommerce product image and 'add to cart' to product page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a featured products area on my website on the homepage, and it works fine at the moment but I'd also like to make the images clickable and once clicked I want them to go to the product page it self. Also, I'd like the woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart to also go to the product page after adding to the cart.

My code:

```
 <div class="featured-products">
               <h1 class="featured-products">Featured Products</h1>
               <?php
                $meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'   => '_featured',
                    'value' => 'yes'
                );
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'   =>  'product',
                    'stock'       =>  1,
                    'showposts'   =>  4,
                    'orderby'     =>  'date',
                    'order'       =>  'DESC',
                    'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
                );

                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                    <li>    
                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 

                            else 
                                echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . ' />'; 
                        ?>
                        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

                        <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

                        <?php 
                            woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );
                        ?>    
                    </li>
            <?php 
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: By default, when you click a product image in WooCommerce - it'll go to a product page. Doesn't it work this way in your case?

Comment: I'm here: https://www.sprinklesandco.co.uk/product-category/easter-decorations/ I click any image and I get to the product page.

Comment: I'm talking about the homepage featured products area I mentioned in the first comment, scroll down slightly after visiting the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' );
```

to this

```
echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_the_permalink( $loop->post->ID ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ) );
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I imagine its a similar workaround to make the 'add to cart' buttons link to the page as well? This line of code here I'm talking about -  woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean, because when I click "Buy Now" it brought to the product page...

Comment: I just resolved the issue myself from your code, thanks anyway dude!